# Selector for first li in a list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

I know there is a way to select the first level, or second level etc of each `li`, but is there a way to simply select the first `li` if the li's are all on the same level?

Does not need to be IE compatible.

`li:first-child` is what I have been investigating but I do not think the use of it is correct

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think `li:first-child` is incorrect? [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) states:

> The :first-child selector is used to select the specified selector,
>   only if it is the first child of its parent.

In this particular case, "specified selector" is the list element (`li`) and its parent is the list itself (`ul` or `ol`), so "the first child of its parent" will be nothing else than the first element of the list. You can see a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mF4QV/